# Cameras battery dies. What happens to video?

Tags: video

Let's say the battery dies or you take it out while recording what would happen to the video?

I believe this camera is from 2006.

I have heard new cameras have a cache that it fixes upon reboot.  Is there a date where this is assumed?  I guess does my camera have this feature?

Answer (score 1):

If the last file the camera recorded is corrupted, you may be able to recover it with Untrunc: https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say the battery dies or you take it out while recording what would happen to the video?

Why can't you try it? Just start video recording and remove battery.

As I can see, you have camera using DV tape, so you will nothing lose of the recorded data.

If you have DVD camera, sdcard or HDD, things get worse, as you must "finalize" recording. In case power loss with HDD/sdcard, you can lost few last seconds/minutes or whole file. Some cameras writes temporary `.dat` files, which can not be played. But it can be repaired. Sometimes it's no easy, but it's possible to get back your data. I can't say anything about DVD, as I not expert in this area. So, just do experiment!

Comment: So I believe it writes video ever 13 minutes in my case.  So you don't lose all the video but some at least.

Answer (score 0):

This highly relies on your camera. We would need to get more information about the exact model.

Generally, most modern cameras can stop and save a recording on power loss, especially on normal battery out (The camera generally shuts down because it is sensing a low battery and not when the battery can't deliver enough battery anymore.

Simplest thing is to try, take an empty storing media and try it out.